# Custom Post Type with Input fields to seperate table on database.

Tags: custom-post-types, database, post-meta, google-maps, input

At the moment I'm using a custom post type called 'locations' I would like to be able to put input fields into the custom post type that would store the information such as ( address, type, phone number, etc.. ) in a separate table called 'markers' So when a new post is made it will create a new entry in the table markers from the following input fields / have it updatable or removable when post is either changed or deleted.

I'm not sure where to start to get these linked together to work in such a fashion, I know how to make a insert.php file to add new locations and to create a database but not with wordpress in such a fashion. My apologies but I'm pretty new to SQL and PHP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should avoid creating more tables. Just do it if you really have a good reason to. Note that `wp_postmeta` can store practically any kind of data, and simply using the [`get_post_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) function can do all the job in most cases.

But if you *must* use another table, and taking it generally, then you're looking for the [`save_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) and [`delete_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/delete_post) hooks.

### Replicating custom fields

Because you mention custom fields, if you want to *replicate* the information from `wp_postmeta` to another table, you would do something like:

```
add_action('save_post', 'save_markers');
function save_markers($post_id) {
    global $wpdb;
    $marker = get_post_meta($post_id, 'marker_custom_field', true);
    // go and put $marker on the markers table
    $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO markers ...");
}
```

The above applies also for the `delete_post` hook.

### Metaboxes

But, if you want to store the information directly on the other table, maybe [metaboxes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) suits you better.

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'marker_add_meta_box');
function marker_add_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box( 
        'marker_metabox',
        __('Marker Title', 'your-plugin-textdomain'),
        'marker_metabox',
        'post' 
    );
}

function marker_metabox ($post) {
    wp_nonce_field(plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'your-plugin-texdomain');
    $marker = get_marker_from_another_table();
    ?>
    <label for="marker_field">
        <?php _e('Marker field description', 'your-plugin-texdomain'); ?>
    </label>
    <input type="text" id="marker_field" name="marker_field" value="<?php echo $marker; ?>" size="25" />
    <?php
}
```

And then, for saving it:

```
add_action('save_post', 'save_markers');
function save_markers ($post_id) {
    if (defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE) 
        return;
    if ('locations' != $_POST['post_type'])
        return;
    if (!current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ))
        return;

    /* Here you have $marker and $post_id, then you can just
       do the reference in your markers table. */

    global $wpdb;

    $marker = $_POST['marker_field'];
    $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO markers VALUES ...");

}
```

And of course, you can do more verifications with the code above.

Comment: Having a quick issue with it, I get this response.                                                   
Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_meta_box() in /home/wordpress/public_html/wp/wp-content/themes/wordpress/functions.php on line 215    How would I go about fixing this ?

Comment: I'm sorry, you should use `add_meta_box` in a hook callback. I just edited the snippet, take a look.

Comment: One last error I'm getting, sorry for needing so much help! Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_marker_from_another_table() in /home/wordpress/public_html/wp/wp-content/themes/wordpress/functions.php on line 227

Comment: Oh... I can't help you with this one. =D That's a function call I just put there to describe what you have to do. Please, don't just copy and paste the snippets beucase they won't work, use them as a reference for your own development.

Comment: I have a quick question, thanks for all your help. I have most of it figured out besides for if I use the add and delete hook to replicate the information from the posts_meta db onto the 'markers' db how would I also have it update? That's the last part I'm stuck on.

Comment: Hey @savunit. You need to store a `post_id` reference in you `markers` table to search for it every time you'll save it. Remember that the `save_post` and `delete_post` will give you the `post_id`.

Comment: Yep! I got the $post_id being placed into the markers table to relate them for adding/deleting. I've had the problem anytime I hit update it duplicates the same entry again in the markers table instead of updating the information, this is important because it's being used to reference a map to the meta boxes. It will cause duplicated markers / information on the map.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/BWYMq68Q    <--- This is a pastebin of the part from my functions.php file

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options.

1. Just use the native custom fields in WordPress, unless you have a
   good reason not to, they would suit you fine and work perfectly with
   custom post types.

   http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields
2. Create your own custom fields and tie them into your CPT using wpdb.
   You need a good reason to do this instead of using option1.

   http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb
3. Check out the [pods framework](http://podsframework.org/), it is basically CPT's with more
   control over the DB.

Comment: is performance a good reason to go for option 2? let's say I have 10 fields and I want to display all 10 fields in a listing of posts... i need to do 10 JOINS with metaposts right?

Comment: yes @yeahman, performance is a major reason for option 2. displaying 10 fields in a listing of posts wont be a problem, but SEARCHING and selecting such posts will be. querying 10 metas from wp postmeta will be slow as hell.

Answer (score -1):

```
INSERT INTO `wp_postmeta` (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (*ID*, 'translation', *VALUE*;
```

Where *ID* is the id of the post you're attaching the value for and *VALUE* is the meta value of the "translation" field.

Like I said, doable ... but you'll need a separate INSERT query for each post. You could dump all of these into a single text file and run the entire set in one pass if you want, otherwise it might take as much time as it would to just add the key through the WordPress UI in the first place.

Comment: Welcome to Wordpress SE! In the future, could you *please* post your answer in one go, instead of first posting [garbage](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/55250)? This triggers spam detection algorithms, which might cause your post to be deleted.